# Поиск картинок на которых изображена одна сцена с разных ракурсов

Tags: python, изображения, opencv, искусственный-интеллект

Можете посоветовать алгоритм, который позволяет ответить на вопрос:

> На этих двух картинках изображена одна сцена или нет?

Больших требований к точности не требуется. Нужно чтобы алгоритм мог узнавать изображения при небольших изменениях ракурса. Как например вот тут
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понимаю SIFT алгоритм легко справится с таким, но реализовать его самому довольно сложно. Я же ищу более простой алгоритм который можно реализовать самостоятельно, например на python.

Comment: [а зачем самому реализовывать](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html)?

Comment: @MaxU чтобы улучшить свои знания в этой области

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы сравнить изображения, нужно создать хеши этих изображений и сравнить [расстояние Хэмминга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A5%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0).

Подробнее про этот алгоритм можно почитать в статье [«Выглядит похоже». Как работает перцептивный хэш](https://habr.com/ru/post/120562/)